# Unable to run the ASP.NET Core Web API project in IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created a new ASP.NET Core Web API project using Visual Studio 2019 and without making any changes, run the project under IIS Express. Just nothing happened and when I stop the solution it gives me the below error.
whereas it runs fine when I choose to run under the same solution name. (running fine in ASP.NET core runtime)

Error: iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1

It will be a great help if someone can explain. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there another site running on iis express?

Comment: No, This is a new setup and I tried with asp.net core web API

Comment: tried Restart Vs?
you have  XAMPP  or other virtual server?

Comment: Installed missing IIS features and it started to work. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Install IIS with all the below features checked as it is required for VS studio 2019 and .Net framework 4.6 and above.
IIS hostable web core has allowed running the core application on IIS

[image]